# Java tree node details

Tags: java, jtree

I have built a tree using JTree and I want to obtain the node details(like they appear in the frame drawn [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTree.htm)).

Comment: Post some code or clarify. There's no enum in the default tree model, and the implementation just calls toString() on the user data passed into the node.

Comment: At the hyperlink given above, is a frame with a tree structure, I need the names(preferably as Strings) of the level 1 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode root = (TreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot();
Enumeration childrenEnum = root.children();
while (childrenEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    TreeNode childNode = (TreeNode)childrenEnum.nextElement();
    String childString = childNode.toString();
    // ....
}
```

Check out the docs for [TreeNode](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) (the 'highest level' interface) and [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) (the most commonly used implementation).  DefaultMutableTreeNode offers the getUserObject() / setUserObject() methods if you need to hold more complex data in the tree node.